# Air Native Extension for Mac - "does not have a method named"

Tags: macos, air, flash-builder, ane

I'm adapting an air extension for PC to the Mac.  Successfully creating a project
which "ought to" work, but instead I get

Error #3500: The extension context does not have a method named

The packaged ANE is being loaded successfully, but no calls work.  I suspect
that the initializer is not being called (and nothing is complaining about it).
My evidence being that I removed the initializer and finalizer from the C project
and the behavior did not change.

Any suggestions?

Versions: Xcode 3, Air-15, Flex 4.13, Flash Builder 4.7

Edit: more information;  I discovered that exporting the application as a release build/signed native installer, then installing and running the application, it works
(well, still needs debugging, but the extension methods are being reached).  So the
question simplifies to "what is wrong with the flash builder environment"

Comment: What is the name of the method that you're calling?

Comment: doesn't matter, they all fail the same way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is apparently impossible to use flash builder in conjunction with air native extensions on OSX.

Creating the extension context works without complaint, but calling any of the functions provided

results in "error #3500: The extension context does not have a method named ..."

It cost me a lot of time (and therefore my company's money) to discover that the ANE is actually fine, and can be

invoked outside of flash builder, by an appropriate command line, or by packaging a release executable.

This total package of behavior is very unsatisfactory, and has been known about for at least two years.

Even with the workaround (release packaging, or invoking using a command line) the workflow is

severely degraded.

--

for reference, the most helpful explanation of the workaround is at this URL

http://riawanderer.com/2012/03/27/working-with-air-native-extensions-on-the-mac/       *note the date of this post!*

then search for the panel that follows the text

"Now that simple demo code is ready, let’s run and see what does it do. When you run the app you should see below error indicating that Flex Builder Bug exists :)."